# ReactJS include or import custom or external javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, reactive-programming

I have a very basic question regarding ReactJS and pretty much between being beginner and intermediate.

I have designed my web application UI in webflow and now developing the frontend application in ReactJS.

So, now I have two JS files called mordenizr.js and webflow.js which I have to import in to my ReactJS component and pages JSX files. I wanted to know How could I import external or custom JavaScript files like these in to ReactJS and they are in plain/obfuscated/minified JS and not in ES6 format.

*PS: I have created the project using **create-react-app** so not able to change or see webpack & babel configuration too*

Thank you.

Regards,

Rohit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why `import 'path/to/mordenizr'` and `import 'path/to/webflow'` wouldn't just work.

After all, javascript files (even "plain/obfuscated/minified" ones) are valid ES6, so webpack should be able to import them like normal.

Comment: Thank you, yes it is importing but gives out error but when I dissected further, the error seems to be from the JS file and had to exclude it.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter whether these files are ES6 format or not, `import 'mordenizr'` should work in either case. The reason for this is that when Webpack transpiles your ES6 files, imports will get back to `require` format.

Comment: Thank you and yes the error is in JS file which works fine with normal HTML file but when imported in ReactJS then the error comes up. Had to exclude it.

Answer (score 0):

use
["babel-plugin-import": "^1.0.1"] https://github.com/ant-design/babel-plugin-import  for webpack

example:

```
plugins: ['transform-runtime','transform-decorators-legacy',['import', {
      libraryName: 'antd',
      style: 'css',
    }]]
```